# Chemmacros Experimental Environment Superscript

Tags: chemmacros

I am using the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package to typeset the experimental data of my research report. However, the options provided as settings for the output don't fit my needs. I would like to have atom numbers of the nuclei as superscripts instead of using a dash or a subscript. However, in the documentation a could only find the options side and sub. Is there a way of setting a superscript position?

Currently I am using the following settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\chemsetup[nmr]{delta=(ppm),pos-number=side,use-equal,format = \bfseries,list=true}       
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,per-mode=symbol,detect-all,range-phrase=--}

\begin{document}
\begin{experimental}

\NMR(600)[CDCl3] \val{2.01} (s, \#{24}, \pos{5}), \val{2.31} (s, \#{12},\pos{6})\\
\data{IR} ...

\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

P.S. Is there a reason why the `nmr` option group is setting up the whole look of the experimental section? I was looking through the documentation for a more general option, but then found that this would do it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 2014/01/24 (v4.3) `chemmacros` has the option `pos-number=super`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[compatibility=newest]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\chemsetup{
  modules = spectroscopy ,
  spectroscopy/delta=(ppm),
  spectroscopy/pos-number=super,% <<<<<<<<<
  spectroscopy/use-equal,
  spectroscopy/format = \bfseries,
  spectroscopy/list=true
} 
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty,
  per-mode=symbol,
  detect-all,
  range-phrase=--
}

\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}
  \NMR(600)[CDCl3] \val{2.01} (s, \#{24}, \pos{5}), \val{2.31} (s, \#{12},\pos{6})
  \data{IR} ...
\end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

### original answer:

As you've noticed there is no option for this. You need to redefine `\chemmacros_nmr_position:n`. This should do what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\chemsetup[nmr]{delta=(ppm),pos-number=side,use-equal,format = \bfseries,list=true} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,per-mode=symbol,detect-all,range-phrase=--}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_position:n #1
  {
    \chemmacros_chemformula:x
      {
        \exp_not:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
        \exp_not:n { ^{#1} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{experimental}

\NMR(600)[CDCl3] \val{2.01} (s, \#{24}, \pos{5}), \val{2.31} (s, \#{12},\pos{6})\\
\data{IR} ...

\end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To your PS: this has historical reasons. The `\NMR` command (and some of the options) existed before the `experimental` environment. When I added it all its options were grouped together in the `nmr` option group, too.

Comment: I'll add an option for this to the next release