# How to invert Atom positioning in chemmacros?

Tags: chemmacros

For my Thesis I use the chemmacros Package to typeset my analysis. Unfortunatetly it is common in our group to have a different position when talking about H and C-NMRs.  At the moment I have the following output, when compiling the code below:

**1H-NMR**: δ = 123 (H-10)  **13C-NMR**: δ = 123 (C-10)

What I would like to have is something like

**1H-NMR**: δ = 123 (10-H)  **13C-NMR**: δ = 123 (C-10)

I found that with version 4.3 you are able to define the atom position with the argument \@firstofone, but even with this information I was not able to achieve the goal, since I coudn't quite figure out what kind of argument this is. I also tried the solution proposed here
[Chemmacros Experimental Environment Superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154650/chemmacros-experimental-environment-superscript)

But I also couldnt get the desired output. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup[nmr]{use-equal,format=\bfseries,pos-number=side}

\DeclareChemNMR\HNMR{1,H}
\DeclareChemNMR\CNMR{13,C}

\chemsetup[nmr]{use-equal,format=\bfseries,pos-number=side}

\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}

  \HNMR \val{123} (\pos{10})    
  \CNMR \val{123} (\pos{10})

\end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to teX.SX. Do want this to aplly to only `H`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! This is not implemented in `chemmacros` as of now. I'll post an answer how to solve this as soon as I have the time.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me, and yes for the H would be sufficient. The reasoning behind is, that H's are attached to the numbers whereas the C's are the numbers in the molecule. 
@cgnieder Thanks for your reply too, and if I put it in two environments, would that be possible then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this to work you'll need to redefine `\chemmacros_nmr_position:n`. Below I propose a solution that checks if the current nucleus is H and typesets the position accordingly. (But it leaves the `pos-number` option to have no effect any more.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\NewChemNMR\HNMR{1,H}
\NewChemNMR\CNMR{13,C}

\chemsetup[nmr]{use-equal,format=\bfseries,pos-number=side}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_danleich_hydrogen_tl {H}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_position:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF
      \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
      \c_danleich_hydrogen_tl
      {
        \__chemmacros_nmr_position:n {#1}
        -
        \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
      }
      {
        \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
        -
        \__chemmacros_nmr_position:n {#1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{experimental}
  \HNMR \val{123} (\pos{10})    
  \CNMR \val{123} (\pos{10})
\end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: if you always put parentheses around `\pos` you could include them in the definition:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_danleich_hydrogen_tl {H}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_nmr_position:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF
      \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
      \c_danleich_hydrogen_tl
      {
        (\__chemmacros_nmr_position:n {#1}
        -
        \chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl)
      }
      {
        (\chemmacros_chemformula:V \g__chemmacros_nmr_element_tl
        -
        \__chemmacros_nmr_position:n {#1})
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```